# Is there any specific inject command for nestjs to input array dto

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am making ecommerce application. I want to take input different color from user (basically a seller) for their product if available. For example Shirt have 3 colors White,blue and black. I am using arrays in dto which is as follow:

Now i want to inject different colors of a product. What will be suitable method for this?

Thanks in Advance.

````
@Allow()
@ApiProperty({type: [String]})
color: [string]

} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate if the data req of color is in array format try this

```
@ApiProperty({type:Array})
@IsArray()
color: string[];
```

clinte side :
json data should be like :

```
{
color:['black','white']
}
```

Comment: I implement the same way you did, but there is an issue: It shows arry should be string. I don't why but i am already passing it as string. Plus do i need to define it color range, because, this is possible that user put such color which is not defined then what will be the approach?